# CORS Ajax POST variables empty in live server but work in local server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

After days (and a bit of spamming here and there), I did get CORS to work for my CodeIgniter applications. However, POST variables are empty in the PHP side in live server. the whole $_POST array is empty for some reason. Here is my ajax code:

```
 var postForm = {'e':'sammy'}; //data to process
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.abc.ca/types/add",

            data: postForm,
            dataType : "json",

            cache: "false",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {

                //result here is blank
                alert(result);
            },
            fail: function (result){
            alert(result);
            }


        });
```

and the called php function (without the whole controller class):

```
        function add() {
     //Add new a biz type
      file_put_contents('trial.txt',implode(" | ",$_POST));
      echo $this->input->post('e');
        }
```

Am I missing something? the response from server are ok. but still the file created contains no data and echo prints empty. Any tips please? I have already tried method:'POST' instead of type:'POST'. Get variables pass away successfully.

Is this CI issue or Ajax because it is constant across ff,chrome and Opera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Ajax :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.abc.ca/types/add",
        data: postForm,           
        cache: "false",          
        success: function (result) {
            //result here is blank
            alert(result);
        },
        fail: function (result){
        alert(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks man. It did work but it broke the chain. Now server replies only POST 500 (no OPTIONS response). The add method does nothing except reply what is posted right now so I really can't know which is breaking it. To get status 200, either one or both of headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, or contentType: "application/json" should exist. Losing it.

Comment: update: your solution worked. The 500 error was caused by another method in the same controller class....a missing semicolon. Marking your solution as an answer. thanks and cheers